# h:inputTextArea scrolling automatically to the bottom of the line that is edited

Tags: html, jsf

I have defined an inputTextArea as follows:

```
<s:div id="editor">
<h:inputTextarea id="mytext"   styleClass="editorTextInput" value="#     {algorithm.script}"/>
</s:div>
```

The content is larger that the editor so scroll bars appears automatically.

The problem (which might be a feature that I do not want) is that each time a key is pressed to edit some content (change a word/char or add a word/char) a scrolling is automatically trig-erred so that the line edited is the last visible line in the inputTextArea.

I have not defined any script or attached any event on the div or the inputTextArea.

I have tried to attach events that do nothing but did not work either

```
<s:div id="editor">
<h:inputTextarea id="mytext"   styleClass="editorTextInput" onkeydown="doNothing()" onkeypress="doNothing()" onkeyup="doNothing()"value="#     {algorithm.script}"/>
</s:div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have anything in your styleClass `editorTextInput`? Is it moving to the end of whole text or at the end of the currently selected line ?

Comment: I have just discovered that in the style the width was set as a percentage width: 75%. Putting the width as fixed 1000px for instance fixed the problem. I don't know why.